# Reading user assist registry key c++

Tags: c++, registry

For some reason when I try to open the registry with `keyRegOpenKey()` the function returns an error (it returns the number 2). How can I fix this? My IDE is codeblocks and I am working on a windows XP machine. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //{75048700-ef-11-d0-9888-006097deac}
    HKEY var;
    char bob[1900];
    int k;
    k = RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"software\\microsoft\\windows\\currentVersion\\explorer\\UserAssist\\{75048700-ef-11-d0-9888-006097deac}\\count",&var);

    if (k==ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout<<"CALL 1 WAS SUCCESSFULL : "<<var<<" "<<k<<endl;
        if (RegEnumKey(var,0,bob,200)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            cout<<"CALL 2 WAS SUCCESSFULL "<<bob<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"CALL 2 FAILED: "<<bob<<endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"CALL WAS NOT SUCCESSFULL "<<var<<" "<<k<<endl;
    }

    RegCloseKey(var);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So 2 is file not found. I just realized it's `RegOpenKey` that doesn't create a key if it can't open it, so it's probably getting hung up on that key not existing.

Comment: I can navigate to that part of the registry in regedit so why is this not working? And what can I do to fix this?

Comment: I'm not overly experienced with registry errors. Perhaps you could try `Create` instead of `Open` and check whether it creates a new key or not. I'm pretty sure there's a parameter for that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used create in stead of open,and my program created another registry key.The reason was the registry is case sensitive and that is why I couldn't open it earlier.